# Ubuntuでのシリアル通信port番号割り当て順番

Tags: linux, シリアル通信

Ubuntu18.04でのポート認識順番について質問です。
ホストマシンは、NVIDIA Jetson AGX Xavierです。

あるデバイスを複数個、USBでマシンに接続しようとしています。
このデバイスは1台接続すると、config用とdata用に2ポート認識されます。

下記、2点が疑問点です。
・認識可能なポート数に上限があるのでしょうか
・１度認識されたデバイスはポート番号が保存されるのでしょうか

前者については、このデバイスを追加で1台接続する毎に`$ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/`でポート番号を確認していったところ、ttyACM0からttyACM9までは接続する毎に数字が増えながらポート認識がされるのですが、6台目、つまり11個目のポートになるはずのデバイスを接続すると、ポートの認識がされません。認識可能なポート数に上限があるとすると、どこかで変える事ができるのでしょうか。

後者については、前述の通り基本的にはデバイスを接続した順番に認識されると理解しているのですが、たまに接続順に関係なくポート番号が割り当てられる事があり、この時は元々そのポート番号として認識されていたデバイスは認識不可になります。
ホストマシンを再起動しても解決せず、シャットダウン後数十分してから起動し接続しなおすと接続順にポート番号が認識されるようになります。
デバイスの個体とポート番号がどこかで関連付けて保存されていたりするのでしょうか。

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [第555回　いま，あらためてudev](https://gihyo.jp/admin/serial/01/ubuntu-recipe/0555), [usb-serial のデバイスファイル名を固定する方法](https://pyopyopyo.hatenablog.com/entry/20160223/p1), [PersistentUSBDevices](https://www.domoticz.com/wiki/PersistentUSBDevices), [Fixed tty device assignments in Linux using udev](https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/knowledge-base.entry.html/2016/06/06/fixed_tty_deviceass-XzTf), [Assign a static USB port on Linux](https://msadowski.github.io/linux-static-port/)